# Python: How to join a list of strings to form one string while including commas within the strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example

```
lista = ['one', 'two', 'three,4']
s_headers = ','.join([str(elem) for elem in lista])
```

Desired output

```
"one, two, 'three,4'"
```

Seen output

```
"one, two, three, 4"
```

Comment: The Python `csv` module will do that for you, if you let it write the file.  Otherwise, you will need to do it yourself.  Note that there's no need to call `str(elem)` when things are already strings.  `','.join(lista)` would be exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can include an if-else condition inside generator expression to add `'`s:

```
s_headers = ','.join('\''+elem+'\'' if ',' in elem else elem for elem in lista)
```

Output:

```
"one,two,'three,4'"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would want this unless you were writing a CSV file, and as I said, the Python `csv` module will handle this for you.

However:

```
def quote(s):
    if ',' in s:
        return f"'{s}'"
    else:
        return s

lista = ['one', 'two', 'three,4']
s_headers = ','.join(quote(elem) for elem in lista)
```

Comment: The purpose is to write the list to StringIO while keeping the strings with their commas in them

Comment: No, that's NOT the purpose.  That is merely your implementation.  WHY are you doing this?  What will you do with the data?

Comment: I am mocking csv data extraction. I have succeeded at mocking all headers apart from those that have commas in the text because they are being broken into two texts instead of treading them as one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add condition in order to do that

`','.join([str(elem) if "," not in elem  else f"'{str(elem)}'"  for elem in lista])`

output: "one,two,'three,4'"

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check if your desired separator is part of any of your strings:

```py
def join_quoted(strings, separator=',', quote_char="'"):
    quoted = [f'{quote_char}{s}{quote_char}' if separator in s else s for s in strings]
    return separator.join(quoted)

join_quoted(lista)
```

gives

```
"one,two,'three,4'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def join_list(list):
# create a new list to hold the new strings
new_list = []

for element in list:
    if isinstance(element, str) and ',' in element:
        element = '"' + element + '"'
    new_list.append(element)

new_list = ', '.join(new_list)
return new_list
```

list = ["one", "two", "three,4"]

print(join_list(list))